# DrawingManager and reference to marker

Tags: google-maps, drawing

When we use DrawingManager in google maps API and we have access to the controls ( marker, polyline, etc) how can we have access to the individual elements that we draw?

For example I am using DrawingManager and I click on a marker and put one marker on google map screen. How can I find the reference to that marker from drawingManager object?

Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't come out of the box. You will have to implement the events associated with the drawingmanager class.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#DrawingManager

Something like:

```
var myDrawings = [];

google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'markercomplete', eventMarkerComplete);

function eventMarkerComplete(m) {
  myDrawings.push(m); //the polygon you drew will be added to myDrawings and you can reference it from there.
}
```

Edit: For polyline

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polylinecomplete', eventPolylineComplete);

function eventPolylineComplete(m) {
  myDrawings.push(m); //the polyline you drew will be added to myDrawings and you can reference it from there.
}
```

Comment: How can we solve the same issue when we have Polyline?  in this case I want to have access to the polyline that I get from drawingManager. It looks click even does not work for drawingManager object.

Comment: I have updated the answer for polylines as well. If you have a look at the documentation I linked in the answer you will find events for polygon, rectangle and circle as well.

Comment: I my answer has answered your question could you please mark it as the answer as well. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am looking for an event before 'polylinecomplete' event. Exactly like 'click' event :)

Comment: What do you mean? You want to be able to click on the polyline you created?

Comment: sorry about the delay. I mean when we just click on the line icon to start drawing, the event of clicking fires